# Trying to download modules but python can't find them

Tags: python, numpy, module

So I need some modules for a project and after trying a lot of things and googling a lot of things I still can't get it to work. I used this code to test if the module was working:

import sys

sys.path.append('c:\users\my name\anaconda2\lib\site-packages')

import numpy

x = randn(100,100)

---

And I got this error:

---

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\My Name\Desktop\test.py", line 3, in

```
import numpy
```

ImportError: No module named numpy

---

Any idea why I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Numpy is not installed or installed incorrectly. Provide some information about the platform you are working on and what have you tried so far.

Comment: From the question it looks like you attempted to install Anaconda on Windows unsuccessfully, but without knowing how you tried to do so it's difficult to offer advice.

Comment: How did you try to install numpy?

Comment: I downloaded it from numpy's site at first, found that didn't work, then downloaded Anaconda which also did not work, then I used pip to uninstall then reinstall but that also did not work. Should I try uninstalling Anaconda?

Comment: Did you have a different Python distribution installed before attempting to install Anaconda?

Comment: You can use `pip install numpy` from your command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can try two things:

```
1) which python
```

And see what python you are using. You may be still pointing to old python the system has. In that case add ~/anaconda2/bin to $PATH environment variable.

```
2) sys.path.append('c:\users\my_name\anaconda2\lib\python2.x\site-packages')
```

Usually anaconda library is installed under lib\pythonx.x(the correct python version number)\site-packages. So change that.

If none of the above worked, then just do clean install from scratch all over again.

Comment: His problem is rather related to numpy.

Comment: If it is installed and configured properly it should work.

Comment: There are separate versions of Anaconda available for both Python 2 and for Python 3.

Comment: You can have multiple versions of Anaconda on the same machine as long as the one you are using is properly pointed and configured.

Comment: I have Anaconda for python 2 and 3 installed on the same machine. Both working fine as long as I point the right one.